# Why is my python port-scanner taking so much time to scan?

Tags: python, port-scanning

I'm using this python portscanner, and for some reason, it's been 16+ minutes and no results came up, still in scanning phase.
Where can I add in the code, to make it scan faster?

```
try:
    for port in range(1,1025):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port{}: Open".format(port))
        sock.close()
```

Comment: Have you set [a timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#notes-on-socket-timeouts), or did you ask Python to wait until a connection is established?

Comment: No I have not set a timeout. How do I implement a timeout?

Comment: You start by reading [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), which describes the `settimeout()` method.

Comment: If you have a standard setup with no firewalls or filters.. both hosts wide open to tcp connections.. then this will run fairly quickly.  BUT, if the remote host is not responding (is not running, or is running but has protection against port scans implemented), then your program will just wait and wait for that answer, it will keep trying several times trying to get the remote to respond.  Finally it'll give up.  This can take a long time.. hence why you need to set a timeout, because the default timeout is fairly long.